# Deploy an artifact into Archiva repo using maven POM

Tags: maven, deployment, pom.xml, archiva

I am trying to deploy a specific artifact I have developed to Archiva using the POM file for my project.

I have added the artifact as a dependency in the POM file. I'm not 100% clear on how that 'should be done but I have the following since the kar's name is CNS0103_0.1.kar

`<dependency>
    <groupId>kar</groupId>
    <artifactId>CNS0103_0.1</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency`

What else do I need to add to this POM? The artifact's repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I add to my pom.xml if I want to deploy the artifact to my Maven repo:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://HOST:PORT/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Archiva Managed Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://HOST:PORT/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://HOST:PORT/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```